# Find distance between 2D point and line segment start point

Tags: javascript, vector, trigonometry

This feels like a simple problem but I am bad at algebra.

[image]

I'm trying to find the distance between a point and the start of a line segment at an angle parallel to the segment. I will use the distance to interpolate a value along the line.

I also need to know when the points are outside of the line.

A code example would be appreciated, this is my attempt so far using threejs Vector2D but it isn't behaving as expected.

```
const lineStartOrig = lineStart.clone()

const lineLength = lineStart.distanceTo(lineEnd)

const dotDiff = point2D.sub(lineStart).dot(lineEnd) / lineEnd.dot(lineEnd)


const pointIntersect = dummyLineStart.add(lineEnd)
                                     .multiplyScalar(dotDiff)
                                     .clamp(lineStartOrig, lineEnd)

const value = pointIntersect.distanceTo(lineStartOrig) / lineLength
```

Comment: Hi elliott_l. There's always a few ways to do things :), but I would take the following approach: If we define a line AB, and a test point C, (also I'm assuming  in your diagram that the dotted lines are perpendicular to the line) 1) calc angle between vectors AC and AB (using dot product) 2) calc angle between vectors CA and CB (again using dot product). If both angles are less than 90 then the point is within our bounds and we can proceed to calculate the intercept and distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's useful to anyone, I used the following functions (unfortunately not in .js, but should illustrate the idea)

To calc angle between two vectors and a test point C:

```
float calcAngle(QVector2D& A, QVector2D& B, QVector2D& C)
{
    QVector2D v1 = B - A;
    QVector2D v2 = C - A;
    float v1DotV2 = QVector2D::dotProduct(v1, v2);
    float magV1TimesMagV2 = v1.length()* v2.length();
    float cosTheta = v1DotV2/magV1TimesMagV2;
    float theta = qRadiansToDegrees(acosf(cosTheta));
    qInfo() << "Theta " << theta;

    return theta;
}
```

To get the distance and intersect point which I think the OP is after:

```
float calcDistAlongParallelLineAndIntersectPoint(const QVector2D& A, const QVector2D& B, const QVector2D& C, QVector2D& intersectPoint)
{
    QVector2D v1 = B - A;
    QVector2D v2 = C - A;
    float v1DotV2 = QVector2D::dotProduct(v1, v2);
    float magV1TimesMagV2 = v1.length()* v2.length();
    float cosTheta = v1DotV2/magV1TimesMagV2;
    float dist = v2.length() * cosTheta;

    QVector2D intersectingPoint = C - v1*(dist/v1.length());
    intersectPoint.setX(intersectingPoint.x());
    intersectPoint.setY(intersectingPoint.y());
    return dist;
}
```

A little check for some random points gives:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I posted the solution I used in the end but your answer pushed me in the right direction

Comment: Glad you sorted it- there's always a few ways to skin a cat :)

Answer (score 0):

I went in a slightly different direction but Gremto's answer helped a lot and correctly answered the question so I'm marking that as the solution.

I solved the problem using a gradient function that I found here: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lscGDr

It's in GLSL but here's my ts version using three.js's Vector2

```
interface Line2D {
    x1: number,
    x2: number,
    y1: number,
    y2: number
}  

const dummyLineStart = new Vector2(0, 0)
const dummyLineEnd = new Vector2(0, 0)
const dummyPoint = new Vector2(0, 0)
const dummyLineEndTranslated = new Vector2(0, 0)

//provides an interpolation value between 0 and 1 for a point depending on its 
relative parallel position to a line

//points before the start of the line will return 1
function interpolatePointValueAlongLine(
    line: Line2D,
    pointX: number,
    pointY: number
) {

    //use reusable vecs to prevent reinitialising class every call
    dummyLineStart.set(line.x1, line.y1)
    dummyLineEnd.set(line.x2, line.y2)
    dummyPoint.set(pointX, pointY)

    //code from: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lscGDr
    dummyLineEndTranslated.set(line.x2, line.y2)
                          .sub(dummyLineStart)

    return dummyPoint.sub(dummyLineStart)
                     .dot(dummyLineEndTranslated) / 
    dummyLineEndTranslated.dot(dummyLineEndTranslated)
}
```